# How do I sign a PDF file with a CA certificate (.crt)?

Tags: pdf, latex, signature

I have obtained a CA certificate (a .cert file) issued by Deutsche Bundesdruckerei to digitally sign PDF files. Now I'm wondering how to sign PDF files on Linux in general and Ubuntu in particular.

While LibreOffice seems to be capable to do so when exporting PDFs, I couldn't find a single applications that offers this functionality for existing PDFs.

In my specific use case the PDFs I need to sign are created with LaTeX. Is there a way to make this work on Linux?

I would be particularly interested in an applications which can be used in bash, as I would like to sign a bunch of files.

I found the following list of applications which are said to be able to sign PDFs but none of them does the trick:

http://wiki.cacert.org/PdfSigning

Comment: what "didn't work" about the programs you tried?